# Redirecting output of system calls with perl in an initramfs

Tags: linux, perl, system, io-redirection

I've got this perl script that runs with the initramfs.  I've come across a bunch of little problems I don't understand that are surely related to the shell.  The particular one I'm asking about is this:

```
system("/sbin/e2fsck -f $dev");

system("/sbin/e2fsck -f $dev >/dev/null");
```

The one redirecting to /dev/null fails. Ultimately, I want to be grabbing the output:

```
open IN, "/sbin/e2fsck -f $dev |";
```

But this fails too.

Here's the answer:
 e2fsck needs a terminal for interactive repair.  Passing the -y flag fixed that.   Thanks.

Comment: How does the second `system()` call fail? Also, does the `open IN,...` statement work or not?

Comment: Assuming "simple" values for `$dev`, the first will not involve a shell and the second one will. This may affect the value of `$?` and it may affect the error messages shown, but I can't see how it possibly make one of the two fail.

Comment: For both calls to `system`: 1) What error message do you see if any? 2) What is `$?` immediate after the call? 3) if `$?` was -1, what is `$!` immediately after the call?

Comment: Finally, why do you care about making it work if you're not going to use it?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Run a command and capture its output?

Comment: The second system call fails with "sh: syntax error: bad fd number" and $? == 512.  This is being run with dash, but I don't see why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your `/bin/sh` is really `/bin/dash`? C.f. [this discussion on bad-fd-number](http://diveintomark.org/archives/2006/09/19/bad-fd-number) and [this fix](http://www.stormsim.com/?p=30) which has some suggestions for using a syntax compatible with `dash`.